# Why does rspec-rails skip the middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rack, rspec-rails, rack-middleware

I have a Rails app (3.2.12) that I wanted to add locale switching via HTTP Accept-Language header.

**What I did to achieve that:**

I added rack-contrib to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-contrib', require: 'rack/contrib'
```

ran `bundle install`, added the middleware to my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Locale
```

and inspect the request env my controller:

```
puts request.env.keys.select{|v| v=~/rack/ }
```

The spec I run is a controller spec, it has `render_views` in it.

**My problem:**

There's no `rack.locale` key in the request environment. I double-checked `rake middlware`, it lists `Rack::Locale` toward the end, right before `run MyApp::Application.routes`.

After some debugging I found out that the middleware is never called when I run

```
rspec spec/controllers/authentication_controller_spec.rb
```

**BUT:** Running the same code in `script/rails s thin` gives me more keys in the request env, namely:

```
rack.request.cookie_string
rack.locale
rack.request.query_string
rack.request.query_hash
```

So, I guess the question is: **Why does RSpec refuse to pick up a Rack middleware?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Controller specs do not go through the stack, they pretty much call directly on the controller itself. You'll probably want to use Rspec's request type tests for this.